# Using derived attributes in same processor in Apache Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I am adding two attributes in update attribute in which one depends on the other.
For example: say I create an attribute a = "Hello" and another attribute b=${a}.
 Then the value of "b" is set to an empty string.
Is there any way in Nifi to use the value of "a" in the same processor or do I always need to create a new processor to use it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently each UpdateAttribute property is evaluated independently of every other configured property (on the same processor). So in order to use "a" to create another property "b", you'd need to add a second UpdateAttribute processor.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Is there a significant performance boost in evaluating the attributes independently ? I would not expect that to be the case, because the attributes are kept in JVM memory, therefore taking dependencies between them into account should not be a big overhead. Am I missing something ?

Comment: You're right, there probably isn't a significant performance boost but the complexity required to implement ordering (especially when using UpdateAttribute's Advanced tab) wasn't worth the effort when adding a second UpdateAttribute satisfies the use-case.